# MacOS: Could not find Headers in Gstreamer 1.14.2 Framework

Tags: macos, gstreamer

I just installed the 1.14.2 on my mac using the pkg. There's no Headers folder!

`/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers` links to  `Versions/Current/Headers`. But there nothing there!

To be clear, `Current` is a symlink to `1.0/` in the same directory

This is what the directory structure of the framework looks like

```
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/                                  
├── Commands -> Versions/Current/Commands          
├── Libraries -> Versions/Current/Libraries                                  
├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources                                                                            
└── Versions                                                                          
    ├── 1.0                                                                                               
    │   ├── Commands -> bin                                                       
    │   ├── Libraries -> lib                                                                                           
    │   ├── Resources                                                         
    │   ├── bin                                          
    │   ├── etc                                                 
    │   │   └── fonts                                         
    │   │       └── conf.d                                                                    
    │   ├── lib                                                                                
    │   │   ├── gio                                                                   
    │   │   │   └── modules                                                                               
    │   │   ├── girepository-1.0                                                  
    │   │   ├── gst-validate-launcher                                                       
    │   │   │   └── python                                                                                  
    │   │   │       └── launcher                                                            
    │   │   │           ├── apps                                                                            
    │   │   │           └── testsuites                                                   
    │   │   └── gstreamer-1.0                                                      
    │   │       └── validate                       
    │   ├── libexec                                
    │   │   └── gstreamer-1.0                          
    │   └── share                                    
    │       ├── fontconfig                                                        
    │       │   └── conf.avail                            
    │       ├── glib-2.0                                                     
    │       │   └── schemas                                                                                            
    │       ├── gstreamer                                                     
    │       ├── gstreamer-1.0      
    │       │   └── validate                         
    │       │       └── scenarios                             
    │       └── locale                                                                        
    │           ├── af                                                                         
    │           │   └── LC_MESSAGES                                                   
    │           ├── am                                                                                    
    │           │   └── LC_MESSAGES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two packages - one with the runtime (which you probably have installed) and the developer package which installs on top of the runtime. Make sure you have both.